# Error on running Inline::C

Tags: perl

Tried to run Inline::C on windows 7 (using active perl 5.14), got some errors.  Not sure where to install the library "bufferoverflowU". Is it really needed?

```
perl te.pl
Set up gcc environment - 4.8.2
C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe C:\Perl64\lib\ExtUtils\xsubpp  -typemap "C:\Perl64\lib\ExtUtils\typemap"  te1_pl_1114.xs > te1_pl_1114.xsc && C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e "mv" -- te1_pl_1114.xsc te1_pl_1114.c
c:/WINBUI~1/bin/gcc.exe -c  -I"C:/winbuild64/test"  -DNDEBUG -DWIN32 -D_CONSOLE -DNO_STRICT -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -DHASATTRIBUTE -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -O2    -DVERSION=\"0.00\"    -DXS_VERSION=\"0.00\"  "-IC:\Perl64\lib\CORE"   te1_pl_1114.c
Running Mkbootstrap for te1_pl_1114 ()
C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e "chmod" -- 644 te1_pl_1114.bs
C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Mksymlists \
     -e "Mksymlists('NAME'=>\"te1_pl_1114\", 'DLBASE' => 'te1_pl_1114', 'DL_FUNCS' => {  }, 'FUNCLIST' => [], 'IMPORTS' => {  }, 'DL_VARS' => []);"
Set up gcc environment - 4.8.2
dlltool --def te1_pl_1114.def --output-exp dll.exp
c:\WINBUI~1\bin\g++.exe -o blib\arch\auto\te1_pl_1114\te1_pl_1114.dll -Wl,--base-file -Wl,dll.base -mdll -L"C:\Perl64\lib\CORE" te1_pl_1114.o   C:\Perl64\lib\CORE\perl514.lib -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lnetapi32 -luuid -lws2_32 -lmpr -lwinmm -lversion -lodbc32 -lodbccp32 -lcomctl32 -lbufferoverflowU -lmsvcrt dll.exp
c:/winbui~1/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lbufferoverflowU
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'blib\arch\auto\te1_pl_1114\te1_pl_1114.dll'

A problem was encountered while attempting to compile and install your Inline
C code. The command that failed was:
  C:\Perl64\site\bin\dmake.exe > out.make 2>&1

The build directory was:
C:\winbuild64\test\_Inline\build\te1_pl_1114

To debug the problem, cd to the build directory, and inspect the output files.

 at te1.pl line 6
    ...propagated at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Inline/C.pm line 798.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at te1.pl line 6.
```

The perl file is very simple

```
use Inline C => <<'END_C';

void greet() {
        printf("Hello, world\n");
}
END_C

greet;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bufferoverflowU` is not a Perl library. It's part of the Windows SDK, though is not included in recent versions. At a guess, you're using ActivePerl, and installed Inline::C using their PPM. Their copy of Inline::C will have been built against whatever version of the Windows SDK they have on their build machines. But you seem to have a newer SDK on your machine.

You could try downloading the latest [Inline::C](https://metacpan.org/release/Inline-C) tarball and building it on your own machine. This will hopefully replace your old copy of Inline::C, and hopefully work.

Comment: Thanks tobyink for the background. PPM for perl 5.16 doesn't support Inline::C, so I had to download the tarball and "installed" it myself. It went well. The only problem is the compile error.  Will try installing SDK.